# C# WPF Bindind DataGrid Columns Properties to list of classes

Tags: c#, wpf, class, binding, datagrid

can anyone help me with binding properties of datagridcolumn? I just don't understand how to do it.

I have DataGrid with columns:
xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RPS, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                          material:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="0 5 3 5"
                          material:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="4 2 2 2"
                          Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">

                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                     
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="##" Binding="{Binding TestNumber}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="State">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding Message}" Height="15"></Image>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            
                           
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColSize" Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Size}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColName" Header="File Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColVehicle" Header="Vehicle" Binding="{Binding Vehicle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColVersion" Header="Version" Binding="{Binding Version}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColDateTime" Header="DateTime" Binding="{Binding DateTime, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss\}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColUnix" Header="Unix" Binding="{Binding ArenaCreationTime}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                           
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                        
                    </DataGrid>
```

And List of columns params:

```
public List<DataGridColumn> Columns { get; set; }
```

class have variables:

```
public class DataGridColumn
{
public string Text { get; set; }
public string SubText { get; set; }
public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
public int Width { get; set; }
public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

So, i don't know how bind columns with that list of classes. Help me pls.

Comment: Where is your Columns property located?

Comment: Columns properties located in class DataGridColumn, i have List<DataGridColumn> Columns in ViewModel of xaml view.

Comment: You have bound the DataGrid to a collection named RPS. Can you show us how that collection and its item class looks like?
What are your purpose and content of the DataGridColumn class?

Comment: How do you think the DataGrid and the Columns collection should work together and what do you expect as the final outcome of this?

Comment: Collection RPS is ObservableCollection of classes which have variables like binding columns. I what to save columns width, visibility and positions, and after restart app restore these parameters. So, I don't know how to bind it.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to your Columns collection in XAML but it is not so easy. And you need to have fixed index numbers in the Columns collection.

This is a starting point for what you can do in the code-behind instead.

This is the saving part in the Closing event handler:

```
private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Extract the properties for each column into the Columns collection
        Columns.Clear();
        foreach (DataGridColumn col in DataGrid.Columns)
        {
            Columns.Add(new MyDataGridColumn() 
            { 
                Text = col.Header?.ToString(), 
                Width=col.Width
                //...
            });
        }
    }
```

Revert the action in the Loading event to set the values.

You may need a little more advanced code to find the correct column. Here I have hardcoded to the first column.

```
    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (MyDataGridColumn col in Columns)
        {
            DataGrid.Columns[0].Header = col.Text;
            DataGrid.Columns[0].Width = col.Width;
    //..
        }
    }
```

Some observations:

Your name of class DataGridColumn conflict with the DataGrid's DataGridColumn. I have renamed your class to "MyDataGridColumn" above.

The DataGridColumn property Width is of type DataGridLength.

Comment: hmmm.... But how i can binding twoway properties and use PropertyChangeEvent?

Comment: In this solution you are not binding the properties, just reading the values when closing and setting the values initially when loading.

Comment: I understand it, so it solution is not good for me. But thanks for the answer anyway.